# PHP - create array from string

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string

I have a string that looks like:

`single=Single&multiple=Multiple2&check=check1&radio=radio2`

how could I create a array like this:

```
array(
  'single' => 'Single',
  'multiple' => 'Multiple2',
  'check' => 'check1',
  'radio' => 'radio2',
)
```

Comment: are you getting request maybe? or not? :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [parse_str](http://php.net/parse_str)

```
parse_str('single=Single&multiple=Multiple2&check=check1&radio=radio2', $data);
```

And in $data you will have your variables.

Comment: Keep in Mind: without using $data you will create a security issue, coz you are loading data into your current scope, so it is crucial to use it :)

Answer (score 5):

If this comes from an URL you can have this *already* as an array in the $_GET or $_POST variables.
Otherwise use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)() to convert string to an array.

Comment: it comes from a hidden form field generated with jquery, like this: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: if you are using ajax(), get() or post() to send it to php you still should have it in the global vars. As an extra suggestion, filter_var the vars that come from js, before using them.

Comment: yes, I do, but only the hidden input (it's all I need). all the other inputs are there just to build this string :)

Comment: it does not matter, those jquery functions send them as POST or GET parameters depending on your request.